# Email Submission form not working- Parse error

Tags: php, forms, validation

So I am basically trying to create a simple photography portfolio website, and decided to put in a contact page as well. Right now I am trying to build a basic email submission form with php but when I inputted the values in the webpage the values disappeared, but I did not receive any emails. I was wondering if the cause is some error in my code, or if I have to turn the webpage into a website for it to send emails.

For furthermore information: I am using xampp to test out the php code and my file directories are: C:\xampp\htdocs and inside the htdocs is a folder called "Photo Website" which has all my webpages, and images.

I ran it through localhost using http://localhost/Photo%20Website/Contact.php and got

**Warning** : mail(): "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header missing in  **C:\xampp\htdocs\Photo Website\Contact.php**  on line  **46**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.min.js">
</script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="webpage.css">
</head>
  <div id="nav">

  <ul>
    <li><a href="Contact.php"> Contact </a></li>
    <li><a href="AboutMe.html"> About Me </a></li>
    <li><a href="Business.html"> Business </a></li>
    <li><a href="Street.html"> Street </a></li>
    <li><a href="Nature.html"> Nature </a></li>
  </ul>
  <p id="logo"><a href="webpage.html"> Icyportraitsgta </a></p>
</div>
<div id="description">
  <!-- Creating the contact forms using HTML !-->
  <form method="post" name="emailform" action="Contact.php">
    Enter Name: <input type="text" name="name"> <br>
    Enter Email: <input type="text" name="email"> <br>
    Message: <textarea name="message"></textarea> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
  </form>
  <!-- Assigned variables using php and used POST !-->
  <?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    ?>
    <!-- Using the above php variables to compose an email message !-->
    <?php
      $email_from = 'alihaider2011@live.ca';
      $email_subject = "New Form submission";
      $email_body = "You have received a new message from the user $name.\n".
                                "Here is the message:\n $message";
     ?>
     <!-- php code to send the email !-->
     <?php
      $to = "dutchland2013@hotmail.com";
      $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
      $headers = "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
      mail($to, $email_subject,$email_body, $headers);
      ?>


</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: upload your file in hosting premium, cannot in localhost

Comment: are you trying it from localhost?in that case is your smtp server configured well?

Comment: Ran it through localhost just now: http://localhost/Photo%20Website/Contact.php

Comment: Got this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?> ' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Photo Website\Contact.php on line 40

Comment: @Rookie You have added `.` instead of `;`  on line 39

Comment: Yea another mistake I have also done is not declaring the $visitor_email as well. However, now I am getting a new error message, which I will show after I update the question